# record Oracle based Windows command script (.cmd) application with loadrunner

Tags: loadrunner

I have a Oracle based Windows Command Script (.cmd ) application, when I open ''mwagui.cmd'' file it will open a Oracle based GUI application and then login to do transactions.

any idea how to launch and record this 'mwagui.cmd' through loadrunner, which protocol we can use for this?

Thanks

Comment: The ORACLE OCI protocol?  Assuming that it is connecting to ORACLE to do work from a thick client application that leverages the ORACLE stanard libraries.   You will probably want to launch the application using the commands which are in the batch file

Comment: Could please suggest which protocol we can use and how can we can handle in loadrunner

Comment: I just did.   Please read the loadrunner documentation on the oracle virtual user protocol

Comment: Note: asking the same question in multiple forums is unlikely to elicit a different path